# Find with arrayFilters using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I have to filter the object which contains only status C in comments(If atleast only comment have the status C then that object alone should be print)  I tried using array Filters but I don't get exact result

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f432a42383a85bb"),
        "projectID" : ObjectId("00000000e614c33390237ce3"),
        "inspection_data" : [ 
            {
                "locationAspects" : [ 
                    {
                        "aspectname" : "Ground floor",
                        "comments" : [ 
                            {
                     "status" :"C",
                                "comment" : [ 
                                    "good"
                                ],
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9974")
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9975")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "aspectname" : "Second floor",
                        "comments" : [ 
                            {
                               "status" :"P",
                                "comment" : [ 
                                    "nothing"
                                ],

                                "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9971")
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9972")
                    }, 
                ],
                "published_date" : ISODate("2018-09-05T07:22:31.017Z"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9976")
            },
          {
                "locationAspects" : [ 
                    {
                        "aspectname" : "Ground floor",
                        "comments" : [ 
                            {
                     "status" :"P",
                                "comment" : [ 
                                    "good"
                                ],
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9974")
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9975")
                    } 
                ],
                "published_date" : ISODate("2018-09-05T07:22:31.017Z"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9976")
            }
        ]
```

Now the inspection data having two object but one object only containing comment status c, So That should be print

**Expected Result**

```
[ {
                    "locationAspects" : [ 
                        {
                            "aspectname" : "Ground floor",
                            "comments" : [ 
                                {
                         "status" :"C",
                                    "comment" : [ 
                                        "good"
                                    ],
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9974")
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9975")
                        }, 
                        {
                            "aspectname" : "Second floor",
                            "comments" : [ 
                                {
                                   "status" :"P",
                                    "comment" : [ 
                                        "nothing"
                                    ],

                                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9971")
                                }
                            ],
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9972")
                        }, 
                    ],
                    "published_date" : ISODate("2018-09-05T07:22:31.017Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f84379f16400f884d9976")
                }]
```

Above object only having the status C if alteast one comment status is C that object alone have to display

Comment: could you paste two documents (the one that should and the one that should not be printed) and the expected output format ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated my Expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to process `inspection_data`. Things are getting complicated since you have multiple levels of nestings, so before you can apply [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) condition you need to get an array of all statuses for single `inspection_data`. To achieve that you can use direct path like `"$$data.locationAspects.comments.status"` but it returns an array of arrays like this:

```
[ [ "C" ], [ "P" ] ], [ [ "P" ] ] ]
```

So you have to flatten that array and that can be achieved using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) and [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html). Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $match: { projectID: ObjectId("00000000e614c33390237ce3") } },
    {
        $project: {
            filtered_inspection_data: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$inspection_data",
                    as: "data",
                    cond: { 
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                statuses: {
                                    $reduce: { 
                                        input: "$$data.locationAspects.comments.status", 
                                        initialValue: [], 
                                        in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] } 
                                    } 
                                }
                            },
                            in: { $in: [ "C", "$$statuses" ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: to match `"C"` or `"P"` you can use replace `{ $in: [ "C", "$$statuses" ] }` with following line

```
{ $or: [ { $in: [ "C", "$$statuses" ] }, { $in: [ "P", "$$statuses" ] } ] }
```

Comment: how do i get response here

Comment: @Vishnu if you use mongoose (based on tags), you can take a look here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Aggregate

Comment: Initially I have to match with project ID how do i match here

Comment: You need additional $match stage, modified my answer

Comment: Am having two more doubt in this in In operation we have mentioned "C" but now i want to print which object contains "c" or "p" and am having array of _id so if the inspection data _id is in that array it should be print

Comment: @Vishnu modified my answer, I'm not sure about the array of _id case and it changes quite significantly initial scope of this question so please create another one regarding array of _id